# Dividing functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{6x-3}$ and $g(x)=x^2-37$. Solve the equation

$$\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)(4)$$

I've plugged $4$ in for $x$ and divided but I must be doing something wrong. Please help

Comment: Why must you be doing something wrong? It doesn't sound like you did anything wrong.

Comment: (f/g)(4)=?? ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing to be *solved* here. What we want to do is *evaluate* the function at $x = 4$, simplifying if possible. If you follow the strategy you speak of, you should obtain $$\dfrac{f(4)}{g(4)} = \dfrac{\sqrt{6(4) -3}}{(4)^2 - 37}=\dfrac{\sqrt{21}}{-21} = -\dfrac{\sqrt{21}}{21}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{21}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, $$\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)(4)=\frac{\sqrt{6\times 4-3}}{4^2-37}=\frac{\sqrt{21}}{-21}$$